# My External Hard Drive is unrecognisable?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

I was attempting to format a hard drive. While it was not showing any rate of completion during formatting process so unplug it immediately. Later my hard drive isn't detected by any device.

Comment: It sounds like your external hard drive is busted.  Either the drive itself or the USB controller inside the device.  Unfortunately in both cases that's a hardware problem and not something we can fix.

Comment: What size of hard drive was this? Was it an SSD? If this was an older device that draws power from the USB bus, there is a decent probability that it was not receiving enough power during the format process, which can cause this sort of problem. A bit more technical info might help someone provide specific support to help you use the external device 